# Determining the Theoretical Maximum Proportion of Data Greater than $\mu + k\sigma$

Tags: probability

Consider a random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. I have observed that for a specific arrangement of data, the proportion of data points greater than or equal to $\mu + k\sigma$ can be maximized. However, I am interested in determining the theoretical maximum proportion of data that satisfies this condition.

In my arrangement, I assume the following:

- The dataset consists of $n$ elements.
- Let $1-r$ proportion of the sample space be equal to $\mu$.
- Among the remaining data, let $p$ proportion of it be equal to $\mu + k\sigma$.
- The remaining data points have the same value such that the mean of the entire dataset is $\mu$. Consequently, the value of these data points can be computed as $\mu - \frac{pk\sigma}{1-p}$.

Based on these assumptions, I have derived the standard deviation $\sigma$ as follows:
$\sigma = \sigma \sqrt{k^2 rp \left(1 + \frac{p}{1-p}\right)}$

By rearranging the equation, I found that $r = \frac{\frac{1}{p} - 1}{k^2}$. In order to determine the maximum proportion of data satisfying $r \leq 1$, subject to the constraint $p \leq 1$, I formulated the following optimization problem:

\begin{align*}
\text{Maximize:} & \quad r \times p = \frac{1-p}{k^2} \\
\text{Subject to:} & \quad r = \frac{\frac{1}{p} - 1}{k^2} \leq 1 \\
& \quad p \leq 1 \\
\end{align*}

After solving the optimization problem, I obtained the values $r = 1$ and $p = \frac{1}{1+k^2}$, which correspond to the maximum proportion of data satisfying the given conditions.

To illustrate the validity of this solution, consider the following example:

Suppose we have a dataset consisting of the following values: [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 9]. The mean of this dataset is 0, and the standard deviation is 3. By applying the derived proportions, we find that 1/10th of the data (the value 9) is greater than or equal to $3 \times \sigma
$. This example demonstrates that the proposed arrangement of data produces the desired maximum proportion.

In light of this example, I am interested in further investigating whether there exists a theoretical upper bound on the proportion of data that can be greater than $\mu + k\sigma$ based on these assumptions. Is it possible to determine this maximum proportion mathematically or derive a closed-form expression for it?

Comment: It seems to me that your question conflates distinctions between theoretical and empirical results. Theoretically, there are no upper bounds since, in the theoretical limit, outcomes approach infinity. Empirically, any upper bound from a random draw amounts to a *supremum*. There's another, deeper assumption implicit in your question: the gaussian or normal distribution where events greater than μ+3σ are very rare. Under differing assumptions such as the Cauchy, such events are much more frequent, even likely.

Comment: there exist upper bounds for the theoretical proportion of outcomes for general r.v. $X$ exceeding $\mu+k\sigma$, and this has been discussed on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1949296